# Как узнать где находится триггер URL через консоль разработчика?

Tags: html, url, request, триггер

Не могу найти триггер URL страницы. Страница вызывает сама себя и в Accept Request видно, что ожидается фото.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Найти src с таким URL не получается. Как через консоль разработчика узнать расположение триггера данного URL? В инспекторе отображается, что страница вызывает сама себя [image: введите сюда описание изображения] , но тип страницы не XHR а text/html. Где искать триггер?

Comment: А если поискать не href, а src?

Comment: Ну по сути это ссылка на главную, не думаю что это может вызвать проблему.

Comment: Простите, перепутал, искал в src. Исправил вопрос.